# Synchronizing a Test Server During Tests

Tags: go

**Summary**: I'm running into a race condition during testing where my server is not reliably ready to serve requests before making client requests against it. How can I block only until the listener is ready, and still maintain composable public APIs without requiring users to BYO `net.Listener`?

We see the following error as the goroutine that spins up our (blocking) server in the background isn't listening before we call `client.Do(req)` in the `TestRun` test function.

```
--- FAIL: TestRun/Server_accepts_HTTP_requests (0.00s)
        /home/matt/repos/admission-control/server_test.go:64: failed to make a request: Get https://127.0.0.1:37877: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:37877: connect: connection refused
```

- I'm not using `httptest.Server` directly as I'm attempting to test the blocking & cancellation characteristics of my own server componenent.
- I create an `httptest.NewUnstartedServer`, clone its `*tls.Config` into a new `http.Server` after starting it with `StartTLS()`, and then close it, before calling `*AdmissionServer.Run()`. This also has the benefit of giving me a `*http.Client` with the matching RootCAs configured.
- Testing TLS is important here as the daemon this exposes lives in a TLS-only environment.

```
func newTestServer(ctx context.Context, t *testing.T) *httptest.Server {
    testHandler := http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "OK")
    })

    testSrv := httptest.NewUnstartedServer(testHandler)
    admissionServer, err := NewServer(nil, &noopLogger{})
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("admission server creation failed: %s", err)
        return nil
    }

    // We start the test server, copy its config out, and close it down so we can
    // start our own server. This is because httptest.Server only generates a
    // self-signed TLS config after starting it.
    testSrv.StartTLS()
    admissionServer.srv = &http.Server{
        Addr:      testSrv.Listener.Addr().String(),
        Handler:   testHandler,
        TLSConfig: testSrv.TLS.Clone(),
    }
    testSrv.Close()

    // We need a better synchronization primitive here that doesn't block
    // but allows the underlying listener to be ready before 
    // serving client requests.
    go func() {
        if err := admissionServer.Run(ctx); err != nil {
            t.Fatalf("server returned unexpectedly: %s", err)
        }
    }()

    return testSrv
}
```

```
// Test that we can start a minimal AdmissionServer and handle a request.
func TestRun(t *testing.T) {
    testSrv := newTestServer(context.TODO(), t)

    t.Run("Server accepts HTTP requests", func(t *testing.T) {
        client := testSrv.Client()
        req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, testSrv.URL, nil)
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatalf("request creation failed: %s", err)
        }

        resp, err := client.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatalf("failed to make a request: %s", err)
        }

    // Later sub-tests will test cancellation propagation, signal handling, etc.
```

---

For posterity, this is our composable `Run` function, that listens in a goroutine and then blocks on our cancellation & error channels in a `for-select`:

```
type AdmissionServer struct {
    srv         *http.Server
    logger      log.Logger
    GracePeriod time.Duration
}

func (as *AdmissionServer) Run(ctx context.Context) error {
    sigChan := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    defer close(sigChan)
    signal.Notify(sigChan, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)

    // run in goroutine
    errs := make(chan error)
    defer close(errs)
    go func() {
        as.logger.Log(
            "msg", fmt.Sprintf("admission control listening on '%s'", as.srv.Addr),
        )
        if err := as.srv.ListenAndServeTLS("", ""); err != nil && err != http.ErrServerClosed {
            errs <- err
            as.logger.Log(
                "err", err.Error(),
                "msg", "the server exited",
            )
            return
        }
        return
    }()

    // Block indefinitely until we receive an interrupt, cancellation or error
    // signal.
    for {
        select {
        case sig := <-sigChan:
            as.logger.Log(
                "msg", fmt.Sprintf("signal received: %s", sig),
            )
            return as.shutdown(ctx, as.GracePeriod)
        case err := <-errs:
            as.logger.Log(
                "msg", fmt.Sprintf("listener error: %s", err),
            )
            // We don't need to explictly call shutdown here, as
            // *http.Server.ListenAndServe closes the listener when returning an error.
            return err
        case <-ctx.Done():
            as.logger.Log(
                "msg", fmt.Sprintf("cancellation received: %s", ctx.Err()),
            )
            return as.shutdown(ctx, as.GracePeriod)
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- There is a (simple) constructor for an `*AdmissionServer`: I've left it out for brevity. The `AdmissionServer` is composable and accepts a `*http.Server` so that it can be plugged into existing applications easily.
- The wrapped `http.Server` type that we create a listener from doesn't itself expose any way to tell if its listening; at best we can try to listen again and catch the error (e.g. port already bound to another listener), which does not seem robust as the `net` package doesn't expose a useful typed error for this.

Comment: BYO listener or `for { c, err := dial(addr);  if err != nil { c.Close(); break; }; time.Sleep(time.Second/10) }`

Comment: I made a utility to help poll services (inter-process) in order to detect when they are ready https://github.com/dm03514/wait-for,  This is similar to the solution that Agis suggests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just attempt to connect to the server *before* starting the test suite, as part of the initialization process.

For example, I usually have a function like this in my tests:

```golang
// waitForServer attempts to establish a TCP connection to localhost:<port>
// in a given amount of time. It returns upon a successful connection; 
// ptherwise exits with an error.
func waitForServer(port string) {
    backoff := 50 * time.Millisecond

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        conn, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", ":"+port, 1*time.Second)
        if err != nil {
            time.Sleep(backoff)
            continue
        }
        err = conn.Close()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        return
    }
    log.Fatalf("Server on port %s not up after 10 attempts", port)
}
```

Then in my [`TestMain()`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Main) I do:

```golang
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    go startServer()
    waitForServer(serverPort)

    // run the suite
    os.Exit(m.Run())
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up adopting: I was working to avoid a non-deterministic sleep (e.g. sleeping for 5 * time.Second), but I implemented a simple wait w/ an exponential back-off before returning a usable test server type. Thanks!